# Upload file to artifactory

Tags: automation, upload, devops, artifactory

I'm trying to upload a zip file (size=1.6GB) to artifactory using CURL, but i have a GATEWAY_TIMEOUT error.

Any help on how to resolve this problem.

[image]

Comment: Do you have an HTTP proxy in front of Artifactory (NginX, Apache httpd etc.)?
Please share more info regarding your setup, preferably not as a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

I tried to figure this out myself, and I figured out that JFrog has a tool specifically for this purpose.

I would use [jfrog-cli](https://jfrog.com/getcli/). This is the supported way to upload objects to Artifactory.

Once you get it installed, you configure it with "jfrog rt config" and you put info about your instance, and your credentials (an API key is best), and then uploading is as simple as "jfrog rt u name_of_file name_of_artifactory_repo"